# form will not display alert upon submission

Tags: javascript

So I've created a form that needs to alert the user the form has been submitted without actually submitting the form anywhere. I've tried to set an alert upon clicking the submit button, but the alert will not show up. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my html and .js code regarding the form.

```js
var validName = false;
var validEmail = false;
var validPhone = false;
var validtxtArea = false;


function validate() {
  if (validName && validEmail && validPhone && validtxtArea) {
    alert("Thank you for submitting your form!");
    console.log("Thank you for submitting your form!");
  }
}

document.getElementById("Name").addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  validName = (name !== '');
  validate();
});

document.getElementById("Email").addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
  // validEmail = string.indexOf('@') !== -1 && string.indexOf('.') !== -1; //
  validate();
});

document.getElementById("Phone").addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  var phone = document.getElementById("Phone").value;

  validate();
});


document.getElementById("txtArea").addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById("txtArea").value;
  validtxtArea = (txtarea !== '');
  validate();
});
```

```html
<form name="form" id="form" onsubmit="return validate()" method="post" class="text-center border border-light">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for "Name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" class="form-control" required> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for "Email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="email" id="Email" name="Email" class="form-control" required> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for "Phone" class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Phone:</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <input type="tel" id="Phone" name="Phone" class="form-control" minlength=10 maxlength=10 required> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for "Inquiry" class="col-form-label">Reason for Inquiry:</label>
    <div class="col">
      <select name="Reasons" id="inquiry" class="form-control">
        <option value="CateringDefault">Catering</option>
        <option value="PrivateParty">Private Party</option>
        <option value="Feedback">Feedback </option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for "info" id="Info" class="col-form-label">Additional Information:</label>
    <div class="col">
      <textarea class="form-control" id="txtArea"></textarea></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for "Customer" class="col-form-label">Have you been to the restaurant?</label>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="no" name="answer" value="NO" class="form-check-input" checked />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="no">No</label></div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="yes" name="answer" value="YES" class="form-check-input" />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="yes">Yes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for "Choices" class="col-form-label">Best days to contact you:</label>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-check-inline">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="M">M </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="choices" name="choices" value="monday" class="form-check-input">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="T">T </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="choices" name="choices" value="tuesday" class="form-check-input">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="W">W </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="choices" name="choices" value="wednesday" class="form-check-input">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="Th">Th </label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="choices" name="choices" value="thursday" class="form-check-input">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="F">F</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="choices" name="choices" value="friday" class="form-check-input">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">

    <button type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="validate();">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: validate does not return anything and calling validate does not submit a form.

Comment: remove the return in the onsubmit and it'll trigger the validate() function without error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried validating all of the fields at once by tying the validation function to the submit button? That might work better than validating with every typed character.

Maybe

```
function validate(name, email, phone, txtarea) {
  if (name !== "" && email !== "" && phone !== "" && txtarea !== "") {
    alert("Thank you for submitting your form!");
    console.log("Thank you for submitting your form!");
  }
}

document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()

  var email = document.getElementById("Email").value;
  var name = document.getElementById("Name").value;
  var phone = document.getElementById("Phone").value;
  var txtarea = document.getElementById("txtArea").value;

  validate(name, email, phone, txtarea);
});
```

I hope that helps